# Разбить элементы коллекции используя yield

Tags: python, коллекции, yield

Предстоит реализовать функцию intersperse(), которая должна принимать два аргумента, итерируемый источник значений и значение-разделитель, и возвращать такой итератор, который "между" соседними значениями из источника отдавал бы значение разделитель. Помните, что

1. Функция должна возвращать именно итератор;
2. ни один элемент из входного итератора не должен быть получен, пока это значение не потребуют от результирующего итератора (если вообще потребуют!);
3. результирующий итератор не должен вставлять разделитель следом за последним элементом входного потока.

Мое решение, но оно не проходит тест, по другому не понимаю как зайти, конвертировать все в строку, а потом разбивать join?

```
def intersperse(iterab, separator):
    for number, item in enumerate(iterab):
        if len(iterab) - 1 == number:
            yield item
        else:
            yield item
            yield separator

print(list(intersperse([], ",")))
print(list(intersperse([42], "foo")))
print("".join(intersperse(["Hello", "World"], " ")))
print(list(intersperse(range(4), 0)))
```

Сам тест

```
from itertools import islice

from solution import intersperse


def test_intersperse():
    assert list(intersperse([], ",")) == []
    assert list(intersperse([42], "foo")) == [42]
    assert "".join(intersperse(["Hello", "World"], " ")) == "Hello World"
    assert list(intersperse(range(4), 0)) == [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3]


def test_intersperse_laziness():
    # Эта функция-генератор помнит, сколько было итераций когда либо
    def indicator():
        while True:
            indicator.count += 1
            yield "click"
    indicator.count = 0

    clicks = intersperse(indicator(), ",")
    assert indicator.count == 0, "No iterations should be performed yet!"

    first_ten = islice(clicks, 10)
    assert list(islice(first_ten, 3)) == ["click", ",", "click"]
    assert indicator.count == 2, "There are should be just two iterations!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код падает на строке `assert list(islice(first_ten, 3)) == ["click", ",", "click"]`, т.к ему на вход приходит генератор, у которого в строке `if len(iterab) - 1 == number:` пытаетесь брать длину, а её нет. Ошибку можно легко обойти: вы ставите разделитель после текущего элемента сравнивая его индекс с концом (которого  у нас в наличии нет), а нужно ставить перед текущим элементом сравнивая его индекс с первым:

```py
def intersperse(iterab, separator):
    for number, item in enumerate(iterab):
        if number > 0:
            yield separator
        yield item
```

Answer (score 2):

Так то первый же вариант, приходящий в голову - завести булеву переменную и с её помощью проверять условие, первый у нас элемент или уже нет. Хотя через `enumerate` код короче получается, конечно.

```
def intersperse(iterab, separator):
    first = True
    for item in iterab:
        if not first:
            yield separator
        yield item
        first = False
```